# Mocking process argv with native node mock

Tags: node.js, testing, mocking, node-test-runner

I am migrating from `sinon` to the native `node:test` library.

Before I mocked argv with `sinon` like so;

```
import { stub } from 'sinon'

stub(process, 'argv').get(() => ['node-path', 'application-entry', 'first-arg']
```

The following with `node:test` is not working;

```
import { mock } from "node:test"

mock.getter(Process, 'argv').mock.mockImplementation(() =>  ['node-path', 'application-entry', 'first-arg'])
```

I get the following error;

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'methodName' must be a method. Received undefined

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution to this (and mocking many other native libraries with the native mocking library) but in this case I did the obvious and injected argv into a function and didn't bother testing it directly